# How to echo an XML string to an HTML page for debugging?

Tags: php, xml, debugging, escaping

Okay so I have a php script and I need to somehow view the value of one of my variables.  The thing is this variable is a very long string of XML that got returned from a server.  I know it has an error message in it but I need to actually see what it is saying.  If I try and Print or echo the value it only displays part followed by a ... or if I use var_dump it does the same.  I've even gone as far as trying to echo a javascript alert with the value but that fails because there are single and double quotes in the xml causing the alert quotes not to be recognized correctly.  I just need to see the value of this variable.  Any advice?  Thanks.

Edit:
Actually said that wrong.  Echo and print don't display the value correctly because the tags are in <> brackets so it is recognizing as an html tag.

Comment: Could you try writing the string to a file via fopen / fwrite?

Answer (score 20):

You can use [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) to output the XML string so that you can get a plaintext view of it in a browser.

```
<?php echo htmlentities( $xml_string); ?>
```

Alternatively, you can parse the XML string to reveal the error message, but this may be more complicated than what you need.

Answer (score 9):

Try `echo htmlentities($var, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')`

Answer (score 7):

i always use this:

```
echo "<pre>". htmlentities($s) . "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
echo '<pre>'.$xml_string.'</pre>';
```

See also:
[CDATA - (Unparsed) Character Data](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)

Answer (score 2):

i usaly use:

```
echo nl2br(str_replace('<', '&lt;', $xml));
```

as its only the < that are a problem

Answer (score 0):

You could just save the XML string to a file. If it's well-formed XML, you can view it with every browser (and expand/collapse nodes ^^).